# Reading binary big endian files in python

Tags: python, numpy, binary, endianness

I'd like to use python read a large binary file in ieee big endian 64bit floating point format, but am having trouble getting the correct values.  I have a working method in matlab, as below:

```
fid=fopen(filename,'r','ieee-be');
data=fread(fid,inf,'float64',0,'ieee-be');
fclose(fid)
```

I've tried the following in python:

```
data = np.fromfile(filename, dtype='>f', count=-1)
```

This  method doesn't throw any errors, but the values it reads are extremely large and incorrect.  Can anyone help with a way to read these files?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a link to an example of a file like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `>f` will give you a single-precision (32-bit) floating point value. Instead, try

```
data = np.fromfile(filename, dtype='>f8', count=-1)
```